# How to get plotly graphs within jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I am trying to create plotly bar graphs offline within Jupyter notebook. But I am getting the below error message. I am using x and y-axis from the data frame called train. X variable called Sex(Male or female) and Y variable called Survived (1 or 0)

Error message

"PlotlyError: Because you didn't supply a 'file_id' in the call, we're assuming you're trying to snag a figure from a url. You supplied the url, '', we expected it to start with 'https://plot.ly'.
Run help on this function for more information."

```
import plotly
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar, Scatter, Figure, Layout
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True) 
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import numpy as np

data = [go.Bar(x=train.Sex,
            y=train.Survived)]
py.iplot(data, filename='jupyter-basic_bar')
```

Any suggestions on how to get graphs within Jupyter notebook offline?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line: `py.iplot(data, filename='jupyter-basic_bar')`

to `iplot(data)`

Example:

[image]